# Is \x->\x->x alpha equivalent to \x->\y->x?

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

So I know that in  `\x->\y->x` the second x is bound to the first one (correct me of I'm wrong, please) and in `\x->\x->x` the last x is bound to the middle one. But does this make a difference when it comes to alpha equivalence?

Is `\x->\x->x` alpha equivalent to `\x->\y->x` ?

Comment: I would strive very hard to never have to care. *Don't reuse names*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two terms `t1` and `t2` are alpha equivalent, then for any context `E[.]`, `E[t1]` and `E[t2]` reduces to the same term.

Hence, if you have two terms and you find a context which make them reduce to two different terms, you know that they are not alpha equivalent.

Here, you have `t1 = \x.\x.x` and `t2 = \x.\y.x`, take a context which apply two different terms, e.g. `v1` and `v2`, you have:

```
t1 v1 v2 = (\x.\x.x) v1 v2 --> (\x.x) v2 --> v2
```

and

```
t2 v1 v2 = (\x.\y.x) v1 v2 --> (\y.v1) v2 --> v1
```

Thus you can deduce they are not alpha equivalent.

That being said, if you really want to work with alpha equivalence, you should spend time in understanding what is a free and a bounded variable and to ask yourself what does it mean to be alpha equivalent in terms of variables binding.